# Node.js image download with bandwidth limit

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently testing out something at the reddit image download feature of my discord bot. The code below is just a scaffold for testing. I was wondering if there is a way of capping or throttling the bandwidth of an image download from a request response. The image is just downloaded once.

I already used different request modules from npm like [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) and their plugins but none of them worked. I also found the module [ratelimit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ratelimit) but this is very old (last commit 2012) and only supports http-requests (no https).

```
var request = require('request')
var fs = require('fs')

request('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/Eol.jsc.nasa.gov_ESC_large_ISS005_ISS005-E-16279.JPG')
    .on('response', (response) => {
        // limitBandwidth()
    })
    .on('data', (data) => {
        
    })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.jpg'))
```

Comment: Is this package suitable for your job? https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-throttle

Comment: thank you for the good tip. i actually came up with the module https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle . Now it works and I can control the bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

It works with the module [throttle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle). You just have to pass in the throttle in front of the actual createWriteStream-pipe.

```
var request = require('request')
var fs = require('fs')
var Throttle = require('throttle');


var throttle = new Throttle(1024 * 1024 / 2)

request('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/Eol.jsc.nasa.gov_ESC_large_ISS005_ISS005-E-16279.JPG')
    .on('response', (response) => {
        
    })
    .on('data', (data) => {
        
    })
    .pipe(throttle).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.jpg'))
```